# Deleted NOTE on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app

I don't have notes sync to any email account, I don't have iPhone backup.

I deleted a very important note, and I would like it back.

- (I am using standard "Notes" app that is pre-instilled on iOS)

Is there a option to recover the note on iPhone (iOS 6.1.3)

iPhone: 4S-16 gb

Is there any way to recover the deleted note?

Comment: Having lost an important NOTE once, through as far as I could tell no fault of my own, I am now extra-careful about backing them up when I (rarely) make a change in them.

Comment: *pre-instilled* ... I like that concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of recovering notes generally.  If you don't have a backup and did not sync notes to other devices, I see no way of recovering it. If the note had a very high value, perhaps a data forensics company might be able to recover something. But that would cost money.